# Get the Selected Line Numbers from Listview

Tags: java, listview, javafx, fxml

I am doing a program that opens a code from external file and shows it in a listview. The part of a interface looks like as:

[image]

When I select the line from the listview, and click on "link" button, I get the selected line using the following code:

```
        String CodeArea = (String) lstCode.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        Stage dialog = new Stage();
        dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(new Text(100, 100, CodeArea))); //this is just to display the output for testing purpose
```

The main task of this program is to store the line numbers that the user selects and when reopens it later, the selected line numbers should be highlighted.

Is there any way to get the line number instead of selected line content? For example: instead of getting selected line content using `getSelectedItem();` I want to get the selected line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `getSelectedIndex()` for getting the index of your selection.

```
int selectedIndex = lstCode.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
```

Now because you need the line number, which IMHO should not contain `zero (0)`, just add `1` to the index to get the line number.

```
int lineNumber = lstCode.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() + 1;
```

Comment: Pretty simple.. It worked! I don't know why I tried the same way it didn't work before. Thank you.

Comment: will it work in a same way for a multiple selection mode too? do you have any idea?

Comment: If you have multiple selection mode, use [`getSelectedIndices()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/MultipleSelectionModel.html#getSelectedIndices%28%29) instead of `getSelectedIndex()`